# Need help with this probability task

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The task says: There are 15 balls in a box, you draw out 5 of them (without putting the ball back) calculate the probability of the situations:
d)The sum of two biggest numbers are greater than 26.

I know that two highest numbers can be (15,12), (15,13), (15,14), (14,13), but don't know what can I do with that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which numbers do the balls have on them?

Comment: first ball has number 1 on it, second number 2... and fifteen number 15.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to avoid double counting.  Either we draw $15$ and at least one of the numbers $12,13,14$ or we draw both $13$ and $14$ but not $15$.  You might break the first case up into three mutually cases: we draw $15$ and exactly $1$, exactly $2$ or exactly $3$ of the numbers $12,13,14$.  Now we have four mutually exclusive cases, so we compute the probability of each and add them up.

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration works in small cases the best.

Hint: Sort your 5 balls from highest to lowest, as you stated, these are the four (family of) cases where the condition is satisfied.

```
15,14,x,x,x
15,13,x,x,x
15,12,x,x,x
14,13,x,x,x
```

How many different cases are there?  Out of how many? If you don't sort them you have to guard for double counting when (15,14) pair set also includes ball 13.